# SocketTimeOutException for PROXY call using GraphServiceClient, how to configure proxy

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get list of users from Azure B2C Active Directory, for un-proxy environment, my code is running fine, but when I am running it by passing proxy configuration, I am getting "SocketTimeoutException"

Below is my code...

```
GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient;
    
    if (this.proxy.equals("true")) {      
        
        final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(this.clientId)
                .clientSecret(this.clientSecret)
                .tenantId(this.b2cTenant)
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
            new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(Constant.scopes, clientSecretCredential);

        final Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(this.hostAddress, this.hostPort));
        
        final OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .newBuilder()
                .proxy(proxy)
                .build();
                
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .buildClient();
        
    } else {
        
        final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(this.clientId)
                .clientSecret(this.clientSecret)
                .tenantId(this.b2cTenant)
                .build();

        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
            new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(Constant.scopes, clientSecretCredential);
        
        graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();
    }
```

In "if" I am working with PROXY and in "else" I am working without PROXY.

So I have a hostAddress and hostPort which I am passing through command line...I am creating a **ClientSecretCredential** using clientId, clientSecret and b2cTenantId.

Then I am creating a **TokenCredentialAuthProvider** using scope and client secret credential.

For me scope is - https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Then I am creating a **Proxy** using address and port, which I am passing to OkHttpClient. Then I am creating passing all of it to graphClient.

For non-proxy ("else") is working fine, but when I am working through proxy I am getting "Time out". I tried to debug code, but the only exception I could get on calling an API say..

```
final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
```

I am getting "SocketTimeoutException"

I have read multiple documents, github threads, I am not able to understand the problem.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/162

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/158

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, the `/me` endpoint does not support client credential flow. Modify your code and the problem should be resolved.

If you want to [list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in the entire tenant, then you need to use the `/users` endpoint:

`final Users users = graphClient.users().buildRequest().get();`

If you only need to [list a certain user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) information of  tenant, then you can use the `/users/{user id}` endpoint:

`final User user = graphClient.users("{user id}").buildRequest().get();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure proxy for Azure Identity Client too while using client credential builder as shown below

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/pull/12779/commits/89729042a122ecaf4c083ccc18a9e7d565bbec25